# Git list commands sometimes emulate a multi-page terminal, but I'd like output to always be dumped to stdout

Tags: bash, git, stdout, msys

I'm a little confused with the following behavior of `git` commands in the Windows Command prompt.

#### This shows a result comparable to VIM (I think) with interactive list

```sh
git branch -a
```

Result is something like the following and I've no idea what key-combinations to use to scroll through the output (I did notice that `q` ends the output).

[image]

#### But this shows a "normal" result by just dumping the output to stdout

```sh
git show-ref --tags --heads
```

which is what I prefer:

[image]

#### How to make all output be just dumped to stdout?

I'd prefer if all commands work the same way. Esp if I want to automate a `git` command in a batch script or something, I cannot use some kind of interactive shell.

I noticed that this behavior seems to be caused by the `TERM=msys` environment variable setting, which, if absent, behaves the same. I don't know if there's a different setting I can use.

In the end, while the colored result may be fun, I can get that by using Git BASH. But when I run the commands directly from the Windows Command, I'd expect them all to just echo the output to stdout.

I can't remember that this was the behavior previously, so my guess is that I installed something that f'ed things up ;). I'm on Windows 10 for this machine, git, bash etc are latest.

Comment: "I've no idea what key-combinations to use to scroll through the output": like vim, you can use j or k for up and down a line. Spacebar takes you down a page. b takes you up a page. q quits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+branch+behave+like+less

Comment: @Tryer, tx! Last time I used VI(M) was in the early 90s I think, and while I did google for the commands, I couldn't find the correct manpage... Apparently it is called `less`. This helps :).

Comment: @phd, haha, indeed, if you _know_ that the command it is internally behaving as is called `less` I'd for sure have found it. So much for my non-existing unix skills!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what git calls a *pager*. You can disable it for a particular command with:

```
git --no-pager branch -a
```

(Note that `--no-pager` goes between `git` and the subcommand, because it is a global switch).

If you want to configure your system so you don't have to remember that, from `man git-config`:

> `pager.<cmd>`
>
> If the value is boolean, turns on or off pagination of the output of a particular Git subcommand when writing to a tty. Otherwise, turns on pagination for the subcommand using the pager specified by the value of `pager.<cmd>`. If `--paginate` or `--no-pager` is specified on the command line, it takes precedence over this option. To disable pagination for all commands, set `core.pager` or `GIT_PAGER` to `cat`.

That is, you can disable the pager for git-branch only with `git config --global pager.branch false`, for example.

And if you want to disable it for all commands do `git config --global core.pager cat`. Or you can try to set the environment variable `GIT_PAGER=cat`, of course.

Comment: Excellent, this works like a charm! If only I knew what terms to use for googling :D. I used `git config --global --add core.pager cat` to set it globally, which seems to work.